# Adding dependency to OSGI Bundle

Tags: aem

I am trying to setup a  maven project and added following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.granite.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211_1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq-wcm-foundation</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.cq.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq-social-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.172</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.cq.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>cq-social-blog</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

On running maven clean install i am getting the following **error**.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project falcon-utils: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.test.wem:test-utils:bundle:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
>   dependencies at com.adobe.cq.social:cq-social-commons:jar:1.4.172:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.adobe.cq.social:cq-social-commons:jar:1.4.172: Failure to find
>   com.adobe.cq.social:socialcommunities-parent:pom:1.1.34 in
>   https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of adobe has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I do not think this to be proxy issue because this was working before. 
Kindly help me on this.

Thanks,
Jai

Comment: Delete your locale maven repository and retry. It should work

Comment: Yes i tried that. But it is not working. Infact i went on to download the JARs manually. But jar is not available at https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public.

Answer (score 1):

The jar is there at https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/adobe/cq/social/cq-social-commons/1.4.172/

Running mvn clean install -U should force update it..

Comment: cq-social-commons jar is available but one of its dependency jar com.adobe.cq.social:socialcommunities-parent is not available. It cannot be browsed and downloaded due to adobe's policy. I am now stuck and not sure how to setup my project

Comment: @Jai : If you work with other version of dependencies(if there is no major change), then you can try: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.cq.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-social-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.cq.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-social-blog</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>